# How to make Set in Java think two Object is same?

Tags: java, collections, containers

There are two objects:

```java
    private class Monkey{
        String name;

        public Monkey(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return name.equals(((Monkey) obj).name);
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void contain(){
       Monkey monkey1 = new Monkey("Jon");
       Monkey monkey2 = new Monkey("Jon");

        java.util.Set<Monkey> monkeySet = new HashSet<>();
       monkeySet.add(monkey1);

       System.out.println(monkeySet.contains(monkey2));
       // false

       monkeySet.add(monkey2);
       System.out.println(monkeySet.size());
       // 2
    }
```

With HashSet，it think monkey1 and monkey2 are not same object. But in my project, if `monkey1.name == monkey2.name`, then they should be same.

What can I do to make HashSet think monkey1 and monkey2 is same ?

Comment: You also need to override the `hashCode()` method in `Monkey`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to override `hashCode` along `equals` to make this things identical.
Here is an example how to do it:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name);
}
```

please read this good reads to know why you need to do this: [why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265637/3204335)

Answer (score 1):

Hashset uses hashcode of class in equals methods. Currently, you're using default hashcode and equals method returns false. Use following code in your Monkey class and you'll get required result.

```
private class Monkey{
    String name;

    public Monkey(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o)
          return true;
       if (!(o instanceof Monkey))
          return false;

       Monkey monkey = (Monkey) o;

      return name.equals(monkey.name);
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
     return name.hashCode();
   }
}
```

Comment: what if name is null ?

Comment: There will be NullPointerException. We need to handle this case. In this case, you may use "".hashCode(); Mean hash of empty string.